# Alliance equivalent of Krom'gar Quartermaster?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

So I'm finally rolling a realm full of Alliance characters. Dropped a massive $55.00 (**ouch!**) on the realm/faction transfer for one of my characters that I was planning on throwing away with some gold and a few sets of heirloom items.

As I don't care for the look of a lot of the heirloom items, I'm trying to transmogrify them ASAP with better looking items (subjective, of course).

That being said, the questline out in Stonetalon Mountains on the Horde side of the house has **[this lovely NPC](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=42028)** that you can buy rep items for as you grind up your rank in the Krom'gar Army.

Is there any Alliance equivalent in *any* zone? Or am I outta luck on this one?

(Yes, I realize that I can simply buy similar looking items to the ones he sells, but I'm just trying to figure out if there's a similar quest chain on the Alliance side).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This quest line was added to the game as part of The Shattering before Cataclysm, and culminates in Krom'gar dropping a bomb on Cliffwalker Post and Stonetalon Peak.

There is not an Alliance version of this quest line, which has been bought up multiple times on the forums as an imbalance due to the items from the Krom'gar Quartermaster being very useful as a source of low level enchanting materials.

Comment: Well I guess that solves that particular dilemma. I don't suppose there's any similar type NPC/quest series _anywhere_ for Alliance? Even outside of Stonetalon?

Comment: There is a quest line where you play through the same story from the Alliance perspective, but there is no quartermaster who sells gear attached to the quest line.